# Strange log messages during SORM initialization

Tags: scala, sorm

I see that into log during SORM 0.3.8 initialization with 2 entities:

```
[] ?_$5 setInst Int
[] ?_$5 setInst Int
```

What is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue of Scala's library, it has nothing to do with SORM. It should be fixed in coming releases of Scala.